# Make requst to stun server (Coturn)

Tags: c#, stun, turn, coturn, rfc5766turnserver

I`m create a coturn server and check it by TrickleICE https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ . Its work. Now i want to write simple client. I`m connect to server by UDP client:

```
        udpClient = new UdpClient();
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress);
        ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);
        try
        {
            udpClient.Connect(ipEndPoint);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

Then i create header and attribyte byte arrays like it described here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5766

Creating header example:

```
        byte[] header = new byte[20];
        byte[] messageT = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)messageType);
        byte[] messageLength;
        messageLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)attributeLength);            
        byte[] TransactionId = MyTransactionByteArray
        messageT.CopyTo(header, 0);
        messageLength.CopyTo(header, 2);
        TransactionId.CopyTo(header, 4);
```

When I send header without any attrubutes by stun protocol (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3489#section-11.1) server logs says:

```
   handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 0.0.0.0:10000, remote addr "myip":"port" 
   Wrong OLD STUN message received
```

With attributes(like here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5766#section-16):

```
 handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 0.0.0.0:10000, remote
 addr "myip":"port"
```

And I am not getting any response.

```
 IPEndPoint ip = null;
 byte []msg = udpClient.Receive(ref ip);
```

Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. just use this header from newest stun protocol:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5389